# Adding pins to map using Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps-api

Is there a way to add locations and info windows to my own map in .tif format?

I'm using MySQL and PHP.

Can I use Google Maps API pins but not their map?

I thought I can put my georeferenced map (WGS84) and add Google Maps API pins on it.

Is that possible and if it is not with Google Maps API, maybe you can recommend me some other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Google Maps API v3 with Ground Overlays (your tiff image >better is jpg or png for web browsers)

In this example you can see the the imagebounds is the referencing the image.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/groundoverlay-simple.html

```
      var imageBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
          new google.maps.LatLng(40.712216,-74.22655),
          new google.maps.LatLng(40.773941,-74.12544));

      var oldmap = new google.maps.GroundOverlay(
      "http://www.lib.utexas.edu/maps/historical/newark_nj_1922.jpg",
      imageBounds);
  oldmap.setMap(map);
```

Markers can be added to the Google Map that appear on your map(tiff/jpg/png)
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple.html

If your Marker Pins are coming from your MySQL database (using PHP) - see this method for the process
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3.html